# Application stops in client system when form contains reportviewer C#

Tags: c#, report

My Client has Reportviewer 2010 and .Net4 client profile already installed on his system.
however, when he opens a form containing reportviewer, whole application stops unexpectedly.

Comment: Does the application log any errors? Are there any errors in the event views?

Comment: @ryadavilli: IO.FileNotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same things happens to me. I included `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`, `Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll` and `WindowsFormsIntegration` (if your proejct is of type WPF) to the output directory, and everything was fixed.

Comment: That's ok. but what if you want to release your program to those who don't have ReportViewer2012? If you create an InstallProject and add these dll's, it would work even if R.V.2012 was not install.